# Open Source Self-hosted Email Automated CRM

Tags: open-source, email, automation, crm

I've been looking around for a basic open-source/free self-hosted CRM system that does basically this,

Let's say I go and try to sell a product to a business and they say "We'll think about it". I want to be able quickly to input their email, name, and so on, in some kind of a campaign form that will start to email them constantly. Like on the first day, an email will be sent to them saying, "Hey, we popped in today, here are the great features of our product..." And then email them again on the third day saying “Have you thought about how our product could help your business…”, and then every 7th day, something like that. That's automated. Does anyone know of some kind of web application that does this?

Comment: It looks like that you're asking us about some spamming software.

Comment: If I wanted to spam people, I'd throw everyone into a generic newsletter database and email them all at once. I'm trying to stay in front of my customers, not spam them!!

Comment: This sounds exactly like Autopest IIRC... it's been a while since I've looked for similar software, it not open source though... (found out about it thru [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Entrepreneur/comments/3p8mp8/a_curated_list_of_not_very_well_known_services/))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much searching, I found exactly what I was looking for, [Mautic](http://mautic.org/)
Here are some of it's features,

Mautic is marketing automation software (email, social, & more). Install on your own website or create a free hosted account.
The simple 3-step setup process takes less than 5 minutes and you'll be ready to reclaim control of your marketing.
Social Media Marketing

Engage your leads through powerful social media marketing. Listen to your target audience and interact directly with them on their social media platform.
Leads

Effortlessly track both anonymous and known leads. Mautic provides in-depth and detailed lead tracking including page views, time spent on site, and specific interests. Once you’ve begun tracking, you can nurture those leads with an array of powerful processes and Mautic makes it easy.
Campaigns

Flexible, easy-to-use campaign management and drip program creation. Build a campaign and define the actions and events your leads will follow. Automate the process of connecting with leads and nurturing them along the sales funnel.
Forms

Design valuable forms for your campaign to collect information, build lists, give content or market your next webinar with the highly customizable form builder.
Points

Keep track of your lead’s activity and define point systems based on different actions. These points will allow you to trigger events like the sending of an email based on registration for a webinar.
Reports

Use the data gathered from each of your campaigns to improve your marketing efforts. Detailed feedback of campaign reports let you improve and perfect your marketing.

Answer (score 1):

A (web-based) Twitter client like Tweetdeck, Hootsuite and many others alike could do this for you. Maybe a *direct tweet feels less intrusive* than a daily e-mail request  ... ? ;-)

From my personal experience I know you can schedule tweets upfront. I passed a [Hootsuite](https://hootsuite.com/) exam a while ago and tested this functionality. But I would not try to sell products the way you described in your question.

If a customer says "I'll think about it" you just have not convinced him / her yet. **It is a different way of saying "no" to you.** And that conviction or belief in your product will not grow if you start informing by e-mail / direct tweets of whatever afterwards. On the contrary.

Why not try to persuade a prospect differently? If one says "I'll think about it" you might challenge him/her right away and say "I am sorry I have not convinced you up till now. What is needed to strengthen your believe that this product offers you the advantages today". There's many possible sales techniques that will work a lot better than asking for the same rejection over and over again. Among my favourite salesmen with great online / off-line courses/book, tips and tricks, and humorous (but oh-so-true) one liners: Zig Ziglar and Jeffry Gitomer.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation to Hootsuite. I was using the post as an example of what I needed